# ファイルブラウザ風のJavaScriptライブラリは存在しますか？

Tags: javascript

添付の画像のようなユーザーインターフェースを実現出来るJavaScriptライブラリを探しています。どなたか簡単にファイルやフォルダのツリーを表現できるライブラリをご存じありませんでしょうか？
[image]

Comment: この辺の記事から調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [Top 10 Javascript File Managers](https://hackernoon.com/top-10-javascript-file-managers-8o2p34vw), [10 JavaScript file manager libraries to consider](https://dev.to/plazarev/10-javascript-file-manager-libraries-to-consider-1nd5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

このあたりとかかな。

Sencha | Ext JS Examples
https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/examples/kitchensink/?modern#trees

Comment: ありがとうございます！凄く沢山のビジュアルサンプルがありますね。

Comment: こちらのサンプルで試して見ようと思います！

Answer (score 1):

たとえば MUI の Tree View は求めているものに近そうです: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/

> [image]

Comment: ありがとうございます！なるほど…こういうのがあるのですね…ちょっと突っ込んで見て見ます！